# Detect charging on battery powered Arduino

Tags: batteries, diodes, charging

I have an Arduino controlling a load that runs off a 3s li-ion battery. I need a way to detect if the circuit is powered from mains or battery.

My thoughts are that I need to isolate the mains at the position indicated "?" so I can check for a voltage at "Probe". I cannot, however, afford the voltage drop from a diode.

I've looked into using an N-channel MOSFET although the body diode would allow the battery voltage through. P channel MOSFETS would likely also result in too large a voltage drop. A relay would latch in the closed position even after losing mains DC as current will continue to flow through the inductor from the battery.

I'm sure there is an easy solution I'm missing here.

Additional Info: Battery is protected with a BMS. Unfortunately, I don't have a 12.6v CC source to charge so I know the battery won't charge to 100% but I can live with that for now. A small amount of current flows back through the 12v PSU (DC Mains) when connected to the battery but not plugged into mains.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXIJyz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You can't connect lithium batteries directly to a 12V supply. You will damage the supply or batteries or both, and mishandled batteries can be damaged and damaged batteries are unsafe, they can explode or burst into flames. You must use a charger which allows safe charging of lithium batteries. Stop connecting them to a power supply immediately.

Comment: I've been struggling to find good info on the implications of doing this. I figured since the BMS covers over/under voltage and current it would be mostly safe. This is also a package (battery with BMS and paired 12v power supply) that I bought from a retailer which further supported this assumption. The more I think about it, however, the more I'm leaning toward using a 20v power supply with a step-down CC/CV module to charge the batteries at 12.6v. The BMS will cut charging at 4.2V per cell. I have a new circuit diagram I'll post here or possibly start a new thread.

Comment: OK, you need to figure out if it is just a power supply or a real charger. But don't ever rely on the BMS because it is for protection only. An analogy: You have a helmet/airbag for safety, but you still need working brakes on your bike/car for normal operation.

Comment: @Justme good analogy! I plan on coding some protection into the arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Put a shunt in series with the Battery (it's probably easiest to put it in the GND path) and measure the Voltage drop across that resistor. The resistor can be as small as 100 Milliohms which should not hurt as a voltage drop.

This will give you the current flow and direction.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7rivR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Problem is probably, that you need a negative supply for the opamp.

Comment: You don't really need a negative rail for the op-amp, do you? As long as OP only needs a yes/no answer to "are we charging now?" (thus no need for any linearity), you could just run the op-amp with a high gain or open loop (perhaps even swap the inputs then). Just pick an op-amp that doesn't mind inputs going below the negative rail (even LM324 is specified to do just fine in that situation).

Comment: This will indicate if current is flowing or not. But as that is a completely wrong way of charging the batteries anyway, the circuit needs to be changed and after the changes there might be better solutions. Such as charging chip able to tell if external supply is being connected and/or battery being charged/full.

Comment: @Justme as the OP states that the Battery has a BMS I assume that this is a valid way of doing it. But that's a design desicion that's beeing made by the OP and not part of the question.

Comment: @TooTea true, if it's only about that, a simple comparator could do the trick as well.

Comment: @kruemi BMS is not a charger, and thus not a valid way of doing it. BMS simply is the last line of protection for the battery in case of things going wrong, like overcurrent, overvoltage, or undervoltage condition. It won't protect the power supply from malfuntioning if connected to empty pack.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it will do the trick but I may move away from using the 12V PSU as a charger.